# Tree View Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, treeview, telerik

I created a query to get all addresses(child) with in municipality(parent) but it is coming back empty/ Any help is appreciated.

```
drop table #tmp1
go

WITH Emp_CTE AS (
SELECT tablesysID, MunicNo, StreetName       
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT e.tablesysID,e.MunicNo,e.StreetName
FROM table1 e
INNER JOIN Emp_CTE ecte ON ecte.MunicNo = e.MunicNo
)
SELECT *  into  #tmp1
FROM Emp_CTE

select * from #tmp1
```

it will be used in asp.net tree view control.

**Thanks Andomar for your answer, which is correct but I just wanted to share how I solved this problem as follows:**

## 1: make the query as stored procedure that returns xml data type as response like:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_someproc]
    @XmlResponse xml output

AS
BEGIN
    --
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
set @XmlResponse=(SELECT DISTINCT 
               table1.MunicNo + ' ' + table1.StreetName + ' ' + table1.City AS firstRow, table1.MunicNo, table1.StreetName, table1.City, 
                table1.XPOS, table1.YPOS, table1.RollID, table2.Asset_ID, table2.Feature_ID, table2.FeatureName + ',' + table2.Feature_ID + ' ' + table2.[DESC] AS secondRow,
               table2.FeatureName, table2.xxxID, table2.[DESC],table3.WONOs, table3.WONOs + ', ' + table3.AssetType + ', ' +table3.Feature_ID AS workONumber
FROM  table4 INNER JOIN
               table3 ON table4.xxxxID = table3.xxxxID INNER JOIN
               table2 ON table4.Asset_ID = table2.xxx_ID INNER JOIN
               table1 ON table2.StreetName = table1.StreetName AND table3.MunicNo = table1.MunicNo
            for xml auto,root('xml'))
END
select @XmlResponse
```

## 2: Aspx page code:

```
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="rtrvxxxxx" runat="server" >
          <DataBindings>
                        <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding DataMember="table1" TextField="firstRow" ValueField="firstRow" />
                        <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding DataMember="table2" TextField="secondRow"  />
                         <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding DataMember="table3" TextField="workONumber"  />

          </DataBindings>               

        </telerik:RadTreeView>
```

## 3: C# Code:

```
private void loadXmlDocument()
        {
            try
            {
                #region Load and Bind xml to treeview

                XmlDataSource xDS = new XmlDataSource();
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

                xmlDoc = callingdatalayerclass.list_XML();
                xDS.Data = xmlDoc.InnerXml;
                xDS.XPath = "/xml/table1";
                xDS.EnableCaching = false;


                //bind to treeview
                rtrvxxxx.DataSource = xDS;
                rtrvxxxx.DataBind();

                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               ex.Message()}
            }
        }
```

## 4: Data access Layer Code:

```
public static XmlDocument List_XML()
                    {

                            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                            SqlConnection SQLConn = new SqlConnection();
                            SQLConn.ConnectionString = someclass.someotherclass.GetConnectionString();
                            try
                           {
                            SQLConn.Open();
                            SqlCommand custCMD = new SqlCommand("sp_someproc", SQLConn);

                            custCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            custCMD.Parameters.Add("@XmlResponse", SqlDbType.Xml).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                            custCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            if (custCMD.Parameters["@XmlResponse"].Value != null)
                            {
                                string xml = custCMD.Parameters["@XmlResponse"].Value.ToString();

                                xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
                            }
                            return xmlDoc;

                        }
                        catch (Exception exGEN)
                        {
                            throw exGEN;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            SQLConn.Close();

                        }

                    }
```

**Notes:** if you see query has rows those are first layer of treeview and 2ndrow is inner row of 1st row or can call it a child of parentnode, 3rd row is inner row or child row of 2nd row, so if 1st row has some records it will output that, if 2nd row has some reocrds it will ouput that. if you see the databining section in treeview datamember is table name and
textfiled is firstrow, value field could be some other coulmn. Have not worked with asp.net orginal treeview so don't know how that works this is for telerik treeview control. I also found that the speed is way faster if data is slected as xml.  "DS.XPath = "/xml/table1";" <= this code is selecting xml element or root element and then with in that element the first element which by the data is sorted(first row record's table)

Comment: What does a `SELECT tablesysID, MunicNo, StreetName FROM table1` returns?

Comment: returns data of addresses with in municipalities

Comment: <duh> My bad, I'll rephrase: Does that root statement *actually* returns *any* results? For the statement you've given, the only way no results can be returned is if the root statement doesn't return any result. Are you showing us your exact query? Can you execute the statement and verify?

Comment: results with out columns name   1 1,     MAIN
                                        4 1      Hello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your recursive condition:

```
INNER JOIN Emp_CTE ecte ON ecte.MunicNo = e.MunicNo
```

This recurses into the same municipality.  (Except when `MinicNo is null`.)

You haven't posted enough information to find the proper condition, but it might look like:

```
INNER JOIN Emp_CTE ecte ON ecte.tablesysID = e.MunicNo
```

Comment: it's a recursive condition though. Even with 1 value in your table, your dataset will be large. That inner join on Emp_CTE within the cte may need to be moved.

Comment: That's strange, without the `join`, it is no longer recursive!